# collapsed TOC in R Notebook

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, rnotebook

I can't seem to get `collapsed: FALSE` in [r-markdown](/questions/tagged/r-markdown)'s `html_notebook`.

With the below YAML I do not get at collapsed TOC.

```
---
title: "R Notebook TEST"
output:
  html_notebook:
    toc: yes
    toc_float: TRUE
    collapsed: FALSE
    theme: flatly
 ---
```

Did I overlook something in the manual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix your indentations in your `YAML` header, i.e.:

```
---
title: "R Notebook TEST"
output:
  html_notebook:
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: FALSE
    theme: flatly
---
```

This works for me:

[image]